# How do you insert multiple rows into Azure Table Storage from Logic App HTTP Response?

Tags: python, binary-tree

I have a Logic App that pings an API and gets an array of objects as a response. Simple question, but unfortunately not easy to find an answer: how do I make MULTIPLE insertions into Azure Table Storage, i.e., one row insertion for each array item returned from the HTTP response?

Should I be using "For Each" somehow?[image]

Or should I potentially be parsing the JSON, followed by a For Each action?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Over one year since my last comment, I've had the great misfortune of working with Logic Apps on a daily basis since then. My first answer is... don't use Azure Logic Apps. It's a headache of gargantuan proportions. Buggy, laggy, untestable and undeployable. Future You will be very sorry you did anything of importance with Azure Logic Apps. To answer your question, if you want to do this inside the workflow, yes, ForEach is your only option. Alternatively, send your entire array to a second workflow and use the SplitOn feature. 100 item limit per batch though, so pretty useless "feature".